# Delphi calculate hours

Tags: windows, delphi, lazarus

I have a problem with delphi, I created a program that calculates working hours, this is a piece of code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,z,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1:TTime;
begin
  a := StrToTime(Edit1.Text);
  b := StrToTime(Edit2.Text);
  c := StrToTime(Edit3.Text);
  d := StrToTime(Edit4.Text);
  e := StrToTime(Edit5.Text);
  f := StrToTime(Edit6.Text);
  g := StrToTime(Edit7.Text);
  h := StrToTime(Edit8.Text);
  i := StrToTime(Edit9.Text);
  l := StrToTime(Edit10.Text);
  m := StrToTime(Edit11.Text);
  n := StrToTime(Edit12.Text);
  o := StrToTime(Edit13.Text);
  p := StrToTime(Edit14.Text);
  q := StrToTime(Edit15.Text);
  r := StrToTime(Edit17.Text);
  s := StrToTime(Edit18.Text);
  t := StrToTime(Edit19.Text);
  u := StrToTime(Edit20.Text);
  v := StrToTime(Edit21.Text);
  z := StrToTime(Edit22.Text);
  a1 := StrToTime(Edit23.Text);
  b1 := StrToTime(Edit24.Text);
  c1 := StrToTime(Edit25.Text);
  d1 := StrToTime(Edit26.Text);
  e1 := StrToTime(Edit27.Text);
  f1 := StrToTime(Edit28.Text);
  Memo1.Text:=TimeTostr(b-a+d-c+f-e+h-g+l-i+n-m+o-n+q-p+s-r+u-t+z-v+b1-a1+d1-c1+f1-e1);
end;

end.
```

But when I click on calculate, if the total exceeds 24 hours, back to 0, how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you only counting hours? If so, use `StrToInt` instead of `StrToTime`, and use `IntToStr` instead of `TimeToStr`. (As an aside: ever heard of 'arrays'?)

Comment: Are you getting actual start/end times, or just hours worked, from the edit controls? Please show sample data for what you're getting in the `Edit.Text`. (Show the content of `Edit1.Text` and `Edit2.Text`, and what you expect `b - a` to return.)

Comment: Just curious - I wonder what would happen if you hit Calculate while one of those text boxes is empty..........

Comment: @Jerry, there are multiple other problems to deal with before exception handling here. :-)

Comment: Instead of use 28 TEdit, why not just use a stringgrid or another grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to resolve your immediate problem:

1. Declare a new variable `TotalTime` the way you've declared a,b,c, etc.
2. Then remove the last line, and replace it with this:

.

```
 TotalTime := b-a+d-c+f-e+h-g+l-i+n-m+o-n+q-p+s-r+u-t+z-v+b1-a1+d1-c1+f1-e1;
 Memo1.Text:= IntToStr(Trunc(TotalTime))+' day(s), '+ TimeTostr(TotalTime);
```

That should show something like this:
  `3 day(s), 07:04:45`

Besides this change, I would rethink the entire approach if I were you. Learn from what others say here, and don't let yourself be affected by downvotes or negative comments.

Comment: Thank you! Are you a god, thanks also to all others for your patience!

Answer (score 4):

One has to guess about what you really intend, but I think that `a` and `b` represent the start and the end of a working day (respectively), and so does  `c` and `d`, and so on. Then you want, instead of `b - a + d - c + ...`,

```
HoursBetween(a, b) + HoursBetween(c, d) + ...
```

(`uses DateUtils`).

**Update**

In a comment, the OP made a request to also see the minutes. Do:

```
var
  minspan: integer;

...

minspan := MinutesBetween(a, b) + MinutesBetween(c, d) + ...;
Memo1.Text := IntToStr(minspan div 60) + ':' + IntToStr(minspan mod 60);
```

Comment: I tried HoursBetween(); but I get an error, I also declared the function, but does not work.

Comment: unit1.pas(125,54) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Int64", expected "TTranslateString"

Comment: Please please please, if you mention "an error", you should always include the error message with that.

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo: What is the **exact code** that's on line 125 of unit1.pas? We can't see your monitor from here.

Comment: Memo1.Text:=HoursBetween(a, b)+HoursBetween(c, d);

Comment: Giacomo King Patermo: You forgot `IntToStr`: `Memo1.Text := IntToStr(HoursBetween(a, b) + HoursBetween(c, d) + ...)`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Ok thanks, now okay, but to see the minutes?

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo, use `MinutesBetween` instead of `HoursBetween`. I asked you before (in a comment to your question above) to edit your question and provide **sample input** and the output you wanted; if you will do so now, I'm sure we can get you an answer that works for what you need. Please do it that way, though, instead of discussing it in comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved with TotalTime, however I will use your code to beautify everything.